# Infinite loop in cobol program

Tags: infinite-loop, cobol

I am new to old COBOL. I am trying an example on online compiler. But, the code I am using is entering an infinite loop. The code is :

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID.  Conditions.

DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01  Char               PIC X.
    88 Vowel           VALUE "a", "e", "i", "o", "u".
    88 Consonant       VALUE "b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h"
                             "j" THRU "n", "p" THRU "t", "v" THRU "z".
    88 Digit           VALUE "0" THRU "9".
    88 ValidCharacter  VALUE "a" THRU "z", "0" THRU "9".

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
Begin.
    DISPLAY "Enter lower case character or digit. No data ends.".
    ACCEPT Char.
    PERFORM UNTIL NOT ValidCharacter
        EVALUATE TRUE
           WHEN Vowel DISPLAY "The letter " Char " is a vowel."
           WHEN Consonant DISPLAY "The letter " Char " is a consonant."
           WHEN Digit DISPLAY Char " is a digit."
           WHEN OTHER DISPLAY "problems found"
        END-EVALUATE
    END-PERFORM.
    STOP RUN.
```

What I understand (only a rough idea) is that **PERFORM UNTIL** is like **while**, **EVALUATE** is like **SWITCH** and **WHEN** is like **CASE** in **C**. So, shouldn't the loop break on entering a valid character?

Comment: The loop breaks on NOT ValidCharacter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not change anything within the loop. The only code you have within the loop is an `EVALUATE` (changes no data) and four `DISPLAY` statements (changes no data).

Looping whilst changing nothing is an infinite loop.

You need to include a second `ACCEPT` statement after the `END-EVALUATE`.

If you had coded the equivalent in C, you'd have got an infinite loop as well.

Comment: In other words, unlike in C, where we can code a getchar() call in the while condition (and then test its value), in COBOL, the ACCEPT must be its own statement.

Comment: @DavidGorsline Yes. That may be what was being attempted, good shot.

Answer (score 1):

As Bill Woodger said, you didn't change the value of char, so it will keep looping forever.

Moreso, if you correct that issue, the program will still not work properly: you have some strange logic on it:

- It will `PERFORM` while Char has a valid character on it.
- But it will escape the `EVALUATE` if the character is not a Vowel, Consonant or Digit.

My best guess is this is how you attempt it to work:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID.  Conditions.

DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01  Char               PIC X.
    88 Vowel           VALUE "a", "e", "i", "o", "u".
    88 Consonant       VALUE "b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h"
                             "j" THRU "n", "p" THRU "t", "v" THRU "z".
    88 Digit           VALUE "0" THRU "9".
    88 ValidCharacter  VALUE "a" THRU "z", "0" THRU "9".

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
Begin.
    DISPLAY "Enter lower case character or digit. No data ends.".
    MOVE "a" to Char
    PERFORM UNTIL NOT ValidCharacter
        ACCEPT Char
        EVALUATE TRUE
           WHEN Vowel DISPLAY "The letter " Char " is a vowel."
           WHEN Consonant DISPLAY "The letter " Char " is a consonant."
           WHEN Digit DISPLAY Char " is a digit."
        END-EVALUATE
    END-PERFORM.
    DISPLAY "Non-valid character!"
    STOP RUN.
```

Changes:

- I put the `ACCEPT` inside the `PERFORM`.
- Because that, and the way it was declared, Char now has an invalid character (empty space). So i move a valid character ("a") to validate the perform criteria with `MOVE "a" to Char`.
- I got rid of the `WHEN OTHER` line, because if it really is `OTHER`, it means it is not a Vowel, Consonant or Digit, and that's exactly what the `PERFORM` is doing: waiting until there's an invalid character in Char.

My output:

> ```
> Enter lower case character or digit. No data ends.
> d
> The letter d is a consonant.
> e
> The letter e is a vowel.
> q
> The letter q is a consonant.
> a
> The letter a is a vowel.
> 1
> 1 is a digit.
> @
> Non valid character!
>
> COBOL STOP RUN at line 218 in program TEST.CBL
> ```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying. I'm suggesting a "priming ACCEPT" outside the loop, with the second ACCEPT at the bottom of the loop. Everytime the loop decides whether it will be entered, there will be a fresh and current value from the ACCEPT for the code to operate on.

Comment: You only make the OTHER a problem by having the ACCEPT at the "top" of the loop.

Comment: What about `PERFORM WITH TEST AFTER`?  Then you wouldn't need to "prime" Char.

Comment: @ScottNelson I like the priming as often there is something else to do (like a header record) which can be done without complicating the main logic. Read, process header, read, check it is data, or if trailer arrives, file is empty, only going into the processing of the data when there is something there. Also changes the nature of the PERFORM, it is executed at least once. Can't have no input without code for that again cluttering the main data-logic.